# Getting a variable out of an Entry text zone

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm coding an Ip Calculator to train with Python and Tkinter.
As far as I am, I managed to create a UI with a text zone in which the user will write their IP. When they press the OK button, the IP is assigned to the ip_addr var, I tried to print it and it seems to work.

But when I try to use it to display netmask or network it seems my var is nowhere to be found.
How can I retrieve this variable to display result in a second text zone, using the second piece of code (don't mind the print() in it, I will properly embed it in Label and Frame later)

```
import ipaddress
### For Tkinter import problem
try:
    from Tkinter import *
except ImportError:
    from tkinter import *

def ok_env():
    ip_addr = zone_text.get()
    #zone_text.delete(0,END)
    print(ip_addr) #La variable est bien recuperée quand on clique sur le bouton ok, mais pas transferée?

ipcalc_window = Tk()
ipcalc_window.title("IP Calculator")
ipcalc_window.geometry('768x512')
ipcalc_window.minsize(768, 512)
ipcalc_window.config(background='#C5D0DB')

ipcalc_mainframe = Frame(ipcalc_window, bg='#C5D0DB')
ipcalc_subframe = Frame(ipcalc_window, bg='white')

label_title = Label(ipcalc_mainframe, text="Entrez l'adresse IP, au format XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/XX:", bg='#C5D0DB', font=('Consolas', 16))
label_title.pack(pady=5)

zone_text = Entry(ipcalc_mainframe, width=45, bg='white', font=('Consolas', 16))
zone_text.pack()

ok_button = Button(ipcalc_mainframe, text="OK", font=('Consolas', 16), command=ok_env)
ok_button.pack(pady=5)

label_text = Label(ipcalc_subframe, font=('Consolas', 16) )
label_text.pack()

ipcalc_mainframe.pack()
ipcalc_subframe.pack()

ipcalc_window.mainloop()

### Piece of code not working
info4 = ipaddress.ip_interface(ip_addr)
print("> [+] IP:", ip_addr, "\n> [+]")
print("> [+] Addresse Reseau:", info4.network)
```

Hope my English is not to bad, thanks to those who will take the time to read it.

Comment: In `ok_env()`, `ip_addr` is a *local variable* - it simply does not exist outside of that function.  Which isn't necessarily a problem, you just need to do whatever you want with that variable's value inside the same function.

Comment: If i do all my calculations inside the ok_env() function, wont i have the same problem to carry the result out of the function? I 've seen there is a .variable argument that can make the thing possible, but for now i haven't figured how to make it work. If i do all my calculations in this first function is there a mean to send the result to another Entry Text zone?

Comment: You can set the text of a Label or Entry from within the function.  If you really need to make the value of the calculation available elsewhere, you could declare the variable as `global` - the problem is that nothing outside of the function will know whether or not a calculation has even been performed.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your responses Jason. I think i'll have to rethink this piece of code from the beginning instead of trying to adapt my ip calc console version to an UI version. I'll come with an updated version of the code once i've updated it.

Comment: I modified the function as following: `def ok_env():
 ip_addr = zone_text.get()
 info4 = ipaddress.ip_interface(ip_addr)
 label_text = Label(ipcalc_subframe, text=("[+] IP:", ip_addr,"[+] Adresse Reseau:", info4.network, "[+] Masque:", info4.netmask), font=('Consolas', 16), anchor='nw')
 label_text.pack()` and now it seems to work correctly.